# Gathered tasks do not run concurrently unless print statement is commented out. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I was writing a script to do a bunch of long-running tasks concurrently and noticed that only one task would run at a time. After a lot of frustrating trial and error, I figured out that the problem was being caused by some strange interaction between asyncio.sleep() and print() inside a loop within the coroutine that ran each task. As soon as I commented out the print(), everything ran concurrently as expected.

After some searching through the Python docs and with Google, I still have no idea why this happened.

The code example below has been vastly simplified to illustrate the issue.

Note: Python 3.6

```py
async task_coro():

  ...setup the task...

  while not_done():
    print(...some informative status stuff...)

    ## The argument here could be 0.1, 1.0, 10, 100, it doesn't matter.
    ## as long as the above print() call is uncommented nothing works ;_;
    asyncio.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  task_coros = [
    task_coro() for i in range(10)
  ]

  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*task_coros))
  loop.close()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually run. It is missing a `def` for `task_coro`, `not_done` is not defined (and wouldn't change value) and the text in the `print` statement isn't in quotes. Could you amend your example so that it actually has the behaviour you're having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely with some of the code you left out. The example below (which is a running version of your example) doesn't appear to have an issue (i.e. runs without problems):

```
import asyncio


async def task_coro():
    x = 0
    while x < 10:
        print(f'...some informative status stuff ({x})...')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        x += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task_coros = [
        task_coro() for i in range(10)
    ]

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*task_coros))
    loop.close()
```